# Making an Xcode widget that takes in an RSS feed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, twitter, rss, ipod

I'm developing an iPod app and want to include a small widget with streaming RSS feed (of a Twitter, specifically) on the main page.  It needs to be small enough to not be the focal point of the page.  I'm very new to Xcode, and have had trouble finding where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this straightforward RSS Xcode tutorial. Looks like parseXMLFileAtURL method may be of help:

http://gigaom.com/apple/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/